# iOS UIWebView or WKWebView URL redirect

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have an URL: http://listen.streamonomy.com/cooljazzflorida (for example). This is an URL I parse in a PLS file (provided by SHOUTcast radios) for streaming audio. When I open it from a browser (Safari or Google Chrome), this URL is redirected to http://streaming.shoutcast.com/cooljazzflorida?lang=fr-fr and I can play the stream.

However, in my iOS application, using UIWebView or WKWebView, the redirected URL is http://streaming.shoutcast.com/cooljazzflorida_64?lang=fr-fr (then with _64), not the same from the browser, and I have the error "The file you require cannot be found".

Any ideas please ? Thanks.

EDIT: A sample code to illustrate the problem:

https://github.com/iDevelopper/RedirectURLSample.git

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UIWebViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    webView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:webView];

    NSString *urlString = @"http://listen.streamonomy.com/cooljazzflorida";
    /* If you enter this url using Safari browser, the redirected url is:
     http://streaming.shoutcast.com/cooljazzflorida?lang=fr-fr
     */
    NSURL *urlToPlay = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlToPlay];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}

#pragma mark - UIWebView Delegate

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSURL *url = [webView.request mainDocumentURL];
    NSLog(@"DID FINISH The Redirected URL is: %@", url);
    /*
     The redirected url is: (not the same returned by the browser and this url is not found)
     http://streaming.shoutcast.com/cooljazzflorida_64?lang=en-us
    */


    // Set AVPlayerItem with the redirected URL
    // ...
}

@end
```

Comment: Use `AVPlayerViewController` to stream audio/video instead of `UIWebview`

Comment: I don't use UIWebView to play audio but AVPlayer and it works well. I just use UIWebViewDelegate method to know the redirected URL to play and to set AVPlayerItem url.

Comment: Then please update your question with your code to do that

Comment: Edited with sample code, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `_64` address really does not exist and it's Streamonomy's fault to not noticing it yet and fixing their redirection logic. The different redirection target is based on `User-Agent` header in your request. I suspect that Streamonomy is trying to guess the requesting device and query different bitrates. I found you two examples:

`Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 10_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.3.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14C89 Safari/602.1`

redirects to existing URL

`Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1`

redirects to the nonexistent `_64`

Go figure what is the exact threshold :-) Also noticeably, setting a totally bogus UA like `ignoremeidontneedyourhelp` redirects to the "correct" (existing) URL. But it's not an useful strategy if you intend to use that UI/WKWebView for normal public web browsing. Websites could be strangely rendered or otherwise broken.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use: - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task willPerformHTTPRedirection:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)redirectResponse newRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *))completionHandler
{
    NSURLRequest *newRequest = request;
    // Play
    // ...
    
    completionHandler(nil);
}
But don't know if it works when app is in background

Comment: I thought that you want to fix UIWebView/WKWebView giving you wrong redirection. Now you will take the wrong redirection, try to understand it and "correct" it? That will break when Streamonomy changes its redirection scheme (will redirect to some other URLs than your "correction" hack expects). You should be convincing Streamonomy that your browser is a desktop browser, by changing User-Agent. Get a correct redirection directly from the server, prevent needless hacking on your side.